# Monit default log

Tags: logging, monit

I would like to change the default log location for monit which is /var/log/monit to something else say /disk1/log/monit, Does anyone know which file and what parameter I need to change. I tried changing the " set logfile syslog facility log_daemon" but it did not like it. Please let me know if someone know the asnwer!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`set log /disk1/log/monit.log` (since 5.22.0)
or

`set logfile /disk1/log/monit.log` (The logfile form is deprecated, but kept for backward compatibility)

in the Monit configuration file.